# Conjugated Functions and Inner Product

Tags: inner-products, function-spaces

In function spaces, we sometimes define the dot product for two elements $f_1, f_2$ as

$$
(f_1, f_2) \equiv \int_a^b f_1^*(x)f_2(x)\rho(x) \mathrm{d}x
$$

where $\rho(x)$ is the weight function and $f_1^*(x)$ is the conjugate of $f_1(x)$.

There are two things that I do not understand.

1. Why do we need conjugates here? Why are they mathematically necessary? I have made little connections between modules in complex space and function spaces, in both we have the multiplication of the conjugated pair:

   $$
   \lambda = (a+\mathrm{i} b) \implies \lambda^* =  (a-\mathrm{i}b) 
   $$

   such that

   $$
   \|\lambda\|^2 = \lambda^*\lambda\implies \|\lambda\| = \sqrt{(a+\mathrm{i}b)(a-\mathrm{i}b)} = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}
   $$
2. What do conjugate functions look like? For example, what is the conjugate function of $f(x) = 3x^2 +5$ ? Is it associated with imaginary numbers or is conjugate just an idea?

Comment: 1. It just has to do with the definition of inner product. One of the properties an inner product must have is
\begin{equation}
(x,x) \geq 0
\qquad \forall x
\end{equation}
In the case of complex functions,
\begin{equation}
(f_{1},f_{1}) = \int_{a}^{b} \lvert{f_{1}}\rvert^{2} \rho \; \mathrm{d}x \geq 0
\end{equation}
becuase $\rho \geq 0$ (althoguht you didn't mentioned it).

2. Conjugating functions is the same thing than conjugating a complex number. Of course, the conjugate of real-valued functions is themselves.

Comment: @SomeUser Thanks! Just making sure, so for $g(x) = \mathrm{i} f(x)$, the conjungate is then $g(x)^* = -g(x)$?

Comment: Notation: use `\|` for better spaced norm bars.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @IanHsiao, if $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, yes.